# CBErrorDomain Code 1: BLE 4.0: Unable to discover services after connection in didDiscoverServices() ; IOS 8.1.3 ;

Tags: ios, swift

I just started working on making an app scan and connect to a BLE 4.0 Device ( https://www.creatroninc.com/product/bluetooth-low-energy-40-module/?search_query=ble&results=2 )

So far I am able to scan and maintain connection to the module. This module is connected to arduino UNO.

However, I am having troubles getting services for the module. Using debugger and breakpoints, I traced my problem to the didDiscoverServices function, where "error" is not nill. When I print out the error to console I get the following :

**Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=1 "One or more parameters were invalid" {NSLocalizedDescription=One or more parameters were invalid.}**

I have been following online tutorials, but I could never really find a solution to this problem. I am new to all this. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks!

Following is a snippet from the function that is returning error:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
    let uuidsForBTService = PositionCharUUID

    if (peripheral != self.discoveredPeripheral) {
        // Wrong Peripheral
        println("wrong peripheral")
        return
    }

    if ((error) != nil) {
        println("error not nill")
        println("\(error)")        // gives CBErrorDomain Code=1
        return
    }

    if ((peripheral.services == nil) || (peripheral.services.count == 0)) {
        // No Services
        println("lol")
        return
    }

    for service in discoveredPeripheral.services {
        if service.UUID == BLEServiceUUID {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as CBService)
        }
    }
}


func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {

    listDevice.text = peripheral.name
    stateLabel.text = advertisementData.description
    discoveredPeripheral = peripheral



    if (self.verbositySelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        println("inside 1")
        cManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
        println("This is peripheral \(peripheral) " )
        test = true
    }

}
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {

    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([BLEServiceUUID])


}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you attempt to discover the services - the error is being reported in `didDiscoverServices` but it is likely caused by how you attempt to discover the services.

Comment: Just added the didConnectPeripheral function where I am attempting to discover the services.

Comment: I would suggest that you move the `discoveredPeripheral=peripheral` from the `didDiscoverPeripheral` to the `didConnectPeripheral`.  The way it is now if a second peripheral is discovered it will overwrite the value of `discoveredPeripheral`

Comment: thanks let me try that

Comment: Moving discoveredPeripheral=peripheral to didConnectPeripheral is not working. Once I move it, it wont make a connection at all and hence none of the other functions are called.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - you don't initiate a connection to `discoveredPeripheral` - the only reason that it wouldn't connect is if the `if` wasn't entered

Comment: Umm, its not making the BLE connection if I include it in didConnectPeripheral. Just to make sure i'm doing it right, should I move it to the start of the didConnectPeripheral function? that is, before peripheral.delegate = self ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter exactly where you put it - as long as it is set before `didDiscoverServices` is called because that is where you use it

Comment: okay so I tried it again , and so far I notice that it doesn't make connection at all if I take it out of the didDiscoverPeripheral :(

Comment: You are right, because there is no retained copy of the peripheral!

Comment: How do you initialise `BLEServiceUUID` ?

Comment: I just put it outside my ViewController class like this : let BLEServiceUUID = "FFE0"

Comment: That's your problem - it needs to be a `CBUUID`, not a string.  You should say `let BLEServiceUUID=CBUUID.UUIDWithString("FFE0")`

Comment: oh boy ... error is gone now lol. You're a genius! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `discoverServices` needs an array of `CBUUID` objects, not strings.

You should have `let BLEServiceUUID=CBUUID.UUIDWithString("FFE0")`